# iMac G4 on and off on schedule

Tags: macos, mac, imac

I have been googling around and I couldn't find anything regarding this.

I have a iMac G4. I would like to set it up on and off on schedule automatically.

For example: turn on at 10:00am and shut down automatically at 1:00pm

Most pages I have landed in while googling has to do with something else - problem with iMac G4 on and off cycle, which has nothing to do with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it up in
System Preferences > Energy Saver > Schedule

or programmatically with pmset ([documentation](http://www.macos.utah.edu/documentation/administration/pmset.html)).

Comment: I found the solution after I posted (System Preference). Thanks for `pmset`.